# Sennheiser G2 upgrade to G3?

Tags: field-recording, wireless, upgrade

I've been using the Sennheiser G2 for close to five years now and I'm happy with them - they've never let me down. Recently I've been looking at the G3 and wondering if there's any real difference, and would it be worth the cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the UK...

The main reason would be if you want to work in Channel 38 (which is the new designated band for radio mics) a license fee should of course be paid for this. Otherwise if they are G2 **Band E** (look on the back) they still will work legally for the future in the Channel 70 unregulated band - I wouldnt worry about it too much if channel 70 works fine for you.

In terms of overall difference in 'quality' I haven't noticed anything, although I haven't scrutinised them like for like. I would also be interested if anyone has anything on this.

Senns G2s in my view are a great value bit of kit. The stock senn lavs are fine but I have upgraded my ones to trams, which if you have money to burn may be worth considering over a G3 upgrade (unless you would like channel 38 or have different mics already).

Dean - just had a look at your website. Nice work! You probably know all this already. Hopefully someone will approach this from a different angle as I am interested too.

Comment: I don't shoot much in the UK, mostly Africa, Central and South America, Asia, and some in my own back yard. I have also upgraded to Trams and Sankens and it makes a huge difference.